# AccessDenied: User X is not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRole on resource X

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to set up AWS Cloudwatch Agent on a raspberry pi running raspberry pi os (buster). However, I get an error that the aws user (via `aws configure --profile ...`) cannot assume *itself*.

I have tried numerous access policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:user/USER",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

on the user `USER`. And,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:role/cloudwatch-XXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

--

Additionally, I set up a Trust relationship from `role/cloudwatch-XXXXX` to the user `USER`.

#### Local cloudwatch logs:

```
I! Detected the instance is OnPrem
2021/05/17 21:23:23 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json ...
Valid Json input schema.
I! Detecting run_as_user...
Got Home directory: /root
No csm configuration found.
Under path : /logs/ | Info : Got hostname XXXXXXXXX as log_stream_name
Configuration validation first phase succeeded
 
2021/05/17 21:23:23 I! Config has been translated into TOML /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml 
2021/05/17 21:23:23 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json ...
2021/05/17 21:23:23 I! Detected runAsUser: root
2021/05/17 21:23:23 I! Changing ownership of [/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/var] to root:root
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! Starting AmazonCloudWatchAgent 1.247347.6
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! Loaded inputs: net statsd swap cpu disk diskio logfile mem
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! Loaded aggregators: 
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! Loaded processors: delta
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! Loaded outputs: cloudwatch cloudwatchlogs
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! Tags enabled: host=XXXXXXXXX
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:1m0s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"XXXXXXXXXXX", Flush Interval:1s
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! [logagent] starting
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! [logagent] found plugin cloudwatchlogs is a log backend
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! [logagent] found plugin logfile is a log collection
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! will use file based credentials provider 
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! cloudwatch: get unique roll up list []
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! Started the statsd service on :8125
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! cloudwatch: publish with ForceFlushInterval: 1m0s, Publish Jitter: 52s
2021-05-17T20:23:24Z I! Statsd listener listening on:  [::]:8125
2021-05-17T20:23:25Z I! will use file based credentials provider 
2021-05-17T20:23:25Z I! [logagent] piping log from XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX(/var/log/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX.log) to cloudwatchlogs
2021-05-17T20:23:30Z E! [outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Aws error received when sending logs to XXXXXXXXX: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::ACC:user/USER is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::ACC:user/USER
    status code: 403, request id: cc120b11-f086-422f-af23-cc4ee5720936
2021-05-17T20:23:30Z W! [outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Retried 0 time, going to sleep 114.827093ms before retrying.
```

How is it that the user does not have access to itself? Please note that the user also has the AWS-managed `CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy` on it so it shouldn't have a problem pushing logs to cloudwatch logs, as far as i know.

Comment: It is not possible to do what you are trying to do.   You can not assume a user, you can only assume roles.  So a user can't assume itself because it is not a role.

Comment: @JDD I figured. but why is it even trying ?